# Doxygen Main Page

Tags: html, doxygen

I created a .dox file with the following. However I am not seeing the 
information displayed in the main page.

```
/// \mainpage My Personal Index Page
///
/// \section intro_sec Introduction
///
/// This is the introduction.
///
/// \section install_sec Installation
///
/// This is a section.
///
/// \subsection step1 Step 1: Opening the box
///
/// This is a subrection.
```

Answer (score 0):

Bingo. One has to specify the file using INPUT in the Doxyfile.